# can not create HttpSolrClient

Tags: java, solr, httpclient, solrj

I am trying to create an `HttpSolrClient` using `solr-solrj.jar` version `5.5.0` .
Here is the code I try

```
SolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient(URL);
```

when I try this, I get an error

```
    Type 'org/apache/http/impl/client/SystemDefaultHttpClient is
 not assignable to 'org/apache/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient'
```

I use `httpclient.jar` with version `4.4.1` .

Seems like there is something wrong with httpclient.jar but i have checked source code, and it seems okay to me.

Any idea what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Setting up the classpath

```
From /dist
    apache-solr-solrj-*.jar

From /dist/solrj-lib
    commons-codec-1.3.jar
    commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
    commons-io-1.4.jar
    jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.5.jar
    slf4j-api-1.5.5.jar

From /lib
    slf4j-jdk14-1.5.5.jar
```

Code :

```
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SolrjPopulator {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SolrServerException {
    SolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient.Builder("http://localhost:8888/solr/book/upload").build();
    for(int i=0;i<200;++i) {
      SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
      doc.addField("foo", "book");
      doc.addField("id", "book-" + i);
      doc.addField("name", "Java Programming" + i);
      client.add(doc);
      if(i%100==0) client.commit();  // periodically flush
    }
    client.commit(); 
  }
}
```